# Database session still open after spring batch processing

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm currently developing an application that processes a large file file and stores it in a JPA database with spring batch. This happens on request. And after a batch is done you can use the same service to get information about the data loaded in the database on request.

Separately these requests work, but if I try combining them I get an error in my unit tests when persist and flushing entities in the database via the TestEntityManger.

The error is:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

It seems like the database session is not properly closed after the batch processing is done. But this should be handled by spring batch, but it isn't. Is there something wrong with my configuration or do I need to manually close the session? And if so, how can I do that?

My batch configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<Klant> jsonItemReader() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<Klant>()
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>    (Klant.class))
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.json"))
                .name("tradeJsonItemReader")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public KlantItemProcessor processor() {
        return new KlantItemProcessor();
    }

   @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<Customer> writer(){
        return new RepositoryItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .methodName("save")
                .repository(customerRepository)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(RepositoryItemWriter<Customer> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Klant, Customer> chunk(1)
                .reader(jsonItemReader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain to me what I can do to solve it?

Repository code:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends 
PagingAndSortingRepository<Customer, String> {

    Optional<Customer> findCustomerByCustomerProspectNumber(int customerProspectNumber);

}
```

Unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJpaTest
@Import({SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public abstract class BaseAccountRepositoryTest {

    private static final String[] DATA = {
            "/backend/model/exampleCustomer.json"
    };

    @Autowired
    protected TestEntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    protected CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected AccountRepository accountRepository;


    @Before
    public void init(){
        List<Customer> customersList = GsonUtil.fromJson(Customer.class, DATA);
        customersList.forEach(customer -> {

            em.persistAndFlush(customer);

            customer.getAccounts().forEach(account -> {
                account.setCustomer(customer);
                em.persistAndFlush(account);

                account.getTransactions().forEach(transaction -> {
                    transaction.setAccount(account);
                    em.persistAndFlush(transaction);
                });
            });
        });

        assertEquals(DATA.length, customerRepository.count());
        assertEquals(1, transactionRepository.count());
        assertEquals(1, accountRepository.count());


    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ylona can you share your code on github? I solved something similar but was a wile ago and I need a bit of context

Comment: Also are you using @Transactional on your Repository?

Comment: I've added a little bit more code. At the moment I can't share the complete code because we use a lot of internal company packages. I will try to reproduce the problem in a project that I can share. 
I'm not using Transactional in the repository of the unit test. Only in the code classes that make use of the repository directly. I've tried putting it in the repository class, but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using JPA, you need to use the `JpaTransactionManager` because by default, Spring Batch will use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` (more details in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html) of `@EnableBatchProcessing`) which knows nothing about your JPA configuration.

You can make your `BatchConfiguration` extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` or add a bean of type `BatchConfigurer` in your context and specify the `JpaTransactionManager` to use by overriding the `getTransactionManager` method.

Here is an example (from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig)):

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the part that I missed. Thank you!