# Spring Batch Multiple DataSource Session/Entitymanager Closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am trying to Pull Records from SQLServer Database to Persist into Mysql Using Spring Boot and Sprin Batch(JpaPagingItemReader and JpaItemWriter).
I have configured Multiple Datasources.
How ever i am facing with below error.

```
    org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:967)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:377)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:597)
    at net.com.org.batch.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpenOrWaitingForAutoClose(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:413)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doClose(JpaPagingItemReader.java:232)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:135)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
20:10:55.875 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Retrieved dependent beans for bean 'jpaMappingContext': [mySqljobRepository, sqlServerLogsRepository]
```

Below is my Batch,Step Configuration

```
   @Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("mysqlEntityManager")
private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondarySqlEntityManager")
private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("mysqlTransactionManager")
private PlatformTransactionManager mySqlplatformTransactionManager;


@Autowired
@Qualifier("secondaryTransactionManager")
private PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager;


@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Bean
public JpaPagingItemReader itemReader(PlatformTransactionManager secondaryTransactionManager) {
    JpaPagingItemReader<SqlServerJobLogs> serverJobLogsJpaPagingItemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
    serverJobLogsJpaPagingItemReader.setMaxItemCount(1000);
    serverJobLogsJpaPagingItemReader.setPageSize(100);
    serverJobLogsJpaPagingItemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
    serverJobLogsJpaPagingItemReader.setQueryString("select p from SqlServerJobLogs p");
    return serverJobLogsJpaPagingItemReader;
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor itemProcessor() {
    return new DataItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter itemWriter(PlatformTransactionManager mySqlplatformTransactionManager) {
    DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
    return dataWriter;
}

@Bean
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myJob").chunk(100).reader(itemReader(secondaryTransactionManager)).processor(itemProcessor()).writer(itemWriter(mySqlplatformTransactionManager)).build();
}

@Bean(name = "myJob")
public Job myJob() throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob").start(step()).build();
}

@Bean
public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager(){
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception{
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager());
    return  mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}
@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
    return simpleJobLauncher;
}
```

I have Tried to Configure BatchConfigurer.But No luck.
Please let me know if i need to configure anything else apart from the above mentioned details

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your `itemReader` and `itemWriter` methods take a transaction manager as parameter but it is not used. Is that intended? What is `DataWriter`? You said you are using `JpaItemWriter` but there is no such writer in your configuration. Since you are using JPA, you need to use a `JpaTransactionManager`.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud.Is their any explicit way to use jpatransaction manager.?The datawriter is my class where i extend the jpaitemwriter and have my repository to persist the entities.Also how to use the transaction manager which i have set as parameter in reader and writer.?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53670896/5019386. Note this works with v4.1+. Otherwise you can define the `JpaTransactionManager` as a bean in your context and set it on your step through the builder.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud.But, when i over ride the getTransactionManager method which Entity Manager Factory Bean should i pass.Source or Target EntityManager Factory Bean. Does it work if i pass source entity manager factory Bean..?

Comment: Mahmoud,i have configured the BatchConfigurer  as bean,But i am facing with the below error.org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Rollback for RuntimeException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Comment: I have also added the transactionManager to the stepBuilder
stepBuilderFactory.get("myJob").transactionManager(mySqlplatformTransactionManager)
                .chunk(100).reader(itemReader()).processor(itemProcessor()).writer(itemWriter()).build();

Comment: ` no transaction is in progress` means your `JpaTransactionManager` is not being used and the `resourcelessTransactionManager ` is still being used (hence the error). Have you removed or replaced the `resourcelessTransactionManager` with the JPA one?

Comment: Yes Mahmoud . I have replaced the ResourcelessTransaction Manager as Below

MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(mySqlplatformTransactionManager);

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine And also Configured DefaultBatchConfigurer with Overridden setDatasource and SetTransaction Manager Methods with my source Datasource and SourceDataBaseTransactionManager.Still the same error below
Rollback for RuntimeException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Comment: @mahmoudbenhassine,Can you please throw some light on the issue.

Comment: Please share a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on github/gitlab/somewhere so I can reproduce the issue and I will be happy to help.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine  Apologize for delay in response.
Please find the Example Code in the link
https://github.com/chichasonu/Spring-Multi-Ds-Batch .Only Changes you have to make is to add the update datasource values in property files

Comment: I opened an issue on your repo on github. Let's continue the discussion there.

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine. Its working like a charm as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer the question.
A big thanks to @MahmoudBenHassine

1. Providing a custom transaction manager by overriding
   DefaultBatchConfigurer#getTransactionManager works only with Spring
   Batch v4.1+ as said in comments. We need to use Spring Boot v2.1 to
   have Spring Batch 4.1